convergence of signed measures
Say we have a sequence of signed measures, $\mu_n$ on $\mathbb{R}$. If $\mu$ is some signed measure such that $\mu_n((-\infty, t]) \to \mu ((-\infty, t])$ for all $t\in \mathbb{R}$ at which $\mu$ is non-atomic, do we have $\mu_n(f)\to \mu(f)$ for all bounded continuous $f$?
In case all the measures are nonnegative, this is a standard result. In trying to adapt the proof i run into a problem that would be resolved if i knew that the assumptions implied that the $|\mu_n|((-\infty, t]) \to |\mu| ((-\infty, t])$ for all $t\in \mathbb{R}$ ( at which $\mu$ is non-atomic), where $|\cdot |$ means total variation.
